# How many ids does the Youtube API filter permits?

Tags: youtube-api

If I have a list of around 3000+ ids, will the API allow me to pass all of them through the id filter category when using the videos/list endpoint

Comment: you can't tried and see the result ?

Comment: No not all its max is 50. But you can use tokens to get more and loop through them.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube returns a max of 50 videos per page, as stated on the videos/list endpoint, so the id filter will take 50 IDs max.